# APEX Class to transfer Files to External Cloud Storage

Tags: apex, files, file-storage, cloud

Can anyone point me to the SF documentation to write/ transfer files uploaded to SF to an external cloud storage system e.g. GDrive.

I have got an OAuth Script with all the client Key and Private Key but cannot find the calls transfer the files accross

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Take a look at the **[Apex REST Callout Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts)**.  That should give you a good start.

Based on your username, you may want to consider building this out **[in Lightning Flow Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_integrate.htm&type=5)** if possible.  Callouts to external systems are supported in Flow now.  (Very good news there!)

You'll also need to understand how GDrive expects the files to be sent.  The **[Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk)** documentation is the place to look.